# react-redux use the ownProps or redux store

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am working on react-redux project,
and i need to understand what is the right way to receive data into my container.

Is the right way is to recieve it from the store props by pure redux,
or i can pass my args through ownProps? or even both ways are good.

When i worked on both possibilities, i ran into rendering problems.

But if i need to do some logic on my data i want to do it only in the parent and decrease the performence costs by not do it on each child either.

In the bottom line do i need to use ownProps? and if yes in which cases?

Comment: please include code snippets as your question is no clear enough.

as far as I understnad your question, you should connect your containers to the redux store to get the data as props, try to return early or have default props in case redux store does not have the data

Comment: If you are passing data to children, like in a table or list, then you should just pass the data as plain props

Comment: Please include the code snippet of what you have tried thus far.

Answer (score 0):

You could do both. You can either use mapStateToProps and grab data from the store and/or access the data as the second parameter of mapStateToProps:

```
mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  if (ownProps.something) {
    return { .... }
  }

  return { .... }
}
```

Don't forget, you have to return an object from mapStateToProps, so whatever your logic is, make sure you do that.

In either case, the wrapped component will receive the props returned from the mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps and the ownProps as well.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it really depends on what data we are talking about and how you model your components. My rule is to use as less as possible the `connect` helper of Redux. As less components know about the store as better. If you end up passing lots of props from parent to child then you have to rethink what is `connect`ed. It is more or less a matter of composition. Just try to crete more dump/stateless components that deal with just rendering.